# Pandas replacing values in One Column Bases on Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I am trying to find a solution to a problem to replace some values in a column based on values in another column. I am trying to transform a column based on values from another column:

So to provide an example an input toy dataframe is

```
         input_df:


        C   A       V   D   N
        
        9   *apar12 1   0   x1*
        8   bpar    4   8   x2
        7   cpar    7   7   x3
        0   hpar    8   6   x1
        8   apar25  9   4   x2
        9   *apar13 3   2   x2*
        12  hpar    11  0   x1
        7   bpar    4   12  x2
        7   hpar    7   3   x1
```

So in the above dataframe whenever column 'A' contains some thing like 'apar1' ( in the example above 'apar12' and 'apar13') the value of the column 'N' should be 'x1'. So in the example above since the first row with 'apar12' already has the column N with 'x1' we will keep it as it is. However the 6th row with 'apar13' in Col A has the N column value as 'x2' we will change it to 'x1'.

Thus the output dataframe looks like:

```
          final_df = 


            C     A     V   D   N
        
           9    apar12  1   0   x1
           8    bpar    4   8   x2
           7    cpar    7   7   x3
           0    hpar    8   6   x1
           8    apar25  9   4   x2
           9    **apar13    3   2   x1**
          12    hpar    11  0   x1
           7    bpar    4   12  x2
           7    hpar    7   3   x1
```

I have tried using the transforming a row , but its not working.

```
     def rowChangeCol(row): 
       
          if row['A'].str.contains('apar1'):
           
           row['N'] = 'x1'
        
        
          return row
```

Then I use the apply function :

```
          final_df = input_df.apply(rowChangeCol, axis=1)
```

The code/function is not working at all. I will really appreciate help in this regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing:

```py
df.loc[df["A"].str.contains("apar1"), "N"] = "x1"
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    C       A   V   D   N
0   9  apar12   1   0  x1
1   8    bpar   4   8  x2
2   7    cpar   7   7  x3
3   0    hpar   8   6  x1
4   8  apar25   9   4  x2
5   9  apar13   3   2  x1
6  12    hpar  11   0  x1
7   7    bpar   4  12  x2
8   7    hpar   7   3  x1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where(condition, answer if condition True, answer if condition false)`

```
df['N']=np.where(df['A'].str.contains('apar1')&~df['N'].eq('x1'),'x1',df['N'])



    C        A   V   D   N
0   9  *apar12   1   0  x1
1   8     bpar   4   8  x2
2   7     cpar   7   7  x3
3   0     hpar   8   6  x1
4   8   apar25   9   4  x2
5   9  *apar13   3   2  x1
6  12     hpar  11   0  x1
7   7     bpar   4  12  x2
8   7     hpar   7   3  x1
```